# Using Jquery to show more data

Tags: jquery

The following Jquery is to allow clicking on a "Load more" button to show more comments of a post. It works fine for only 1 post and it's comments.
If I want to loop through a group of posts and their comments, and then apply this code to the comments to load more comments upon clicking a button, this will not work properly because the same class/id is looped for all posts.
How can this be done?

```
  $('.post').slice(0,5).show();

$('#btnMore').on('click', function() {
  $('.post:hidden').slice(0,3).slideDown();
  if($('.post:hidden').length === 0) {
    $('#btnMore').fadeOut();
  }
});
```

HTML Added :

```
@foreach($topans as $topanswer)

                   {{$topanswer->body}} 

          <div class="content">
                  @foreach($topanswer->comments as $topanscom)
                      <div class="post">
                     <p>{{$topanscom->comment}} </p>

                      </div>
                  @endforeach

                  <div class="btnHolder">
                     <button id="btnMore">Load More</button>
                  </div>

          </div>
@endforeach
```

CSS :

```
.post {
  display: none;
}
```

Comment: Can you post your HTML also?

Comment: HTML is added above.

Comment: @AbdallahSakre is that symfony or laravel code ?

Comment: Yes, this is laravel

Comment: The answers will only be as accurate as your details...post the end html content, not your source code or people will have to work of assumptions.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Regardless of the way you are generating this html, you need to create a holder to iterate through in order to differentiate the different sets. You will also want to use a class instead of an id for your button.

Note the introduction of the "postSet" container for the divs, and the use of `this` inside of the iterations in order to keep the current targets scoped. While you will use different names and styles, the structure shown here should be easily adapted to your current implementation.

```js
// Iterate the containers for the initial showing
$('.postSet').each(function(){
 // Use `this` in order to reference the current post set container
 $('.post',this).slice(0,5).show();
});

$('.btnMore').on('click', function() {
  // Locate the current container for the post set
  var container = $(this).closest('.postSet');

  // Use the post set container as a reference for scope
  $('.post:hidden',container).slice(0,3).slideDown();
  if($('.post:hidden',container).length === 0) {
    $(this).fadeOut();
  }
});
```

```css
.postSet{
 padding: 1% 3%;
 border: 1px solid black;
}
.post{
 display:none;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<div class="postSet">
  <div class="post">Lorem ipsum</div>
  <div class="post">Lorem ipsum</div>
  <div class="post">Lorem ipsum</div>
  <div class="post">Lorem ipsum</div>
  <div class="post">Lorem ipsum</div>
  <div class="post">Lorem ipsum</div>
  <p><button class="btnMore" type="button">More</button></p>
</div>
<div class="postSet">
  <div class="post">Lorem ipsum</div>
  <div class="post">Lorem ipsum</div>
  <div class="post">Lorem ipsum</div>
  <div class="post">Lorem ipsum</div>
  <div class="post">Lorem ipsum</div>
  <div class="post">Lorem ipsum</div>
  <p><button class="btnMore" type="button">More</button></p>
</div>
<div class="postSet">
  <div class="post">Lorem ipsum</div>
  <div class="post">Lorem ipsum</div>
  <div class="post">Lorem ipsum</div>
  <div class="post">Lorem ipsum</div>
  <div class="post">Lorem ipsum</div>
  <div class="post">Lorem ipsum</div>
  <p><button class="btnMore" type="button">More</button></p>
</div>
```

Comment: Can you please slow down next time :)  I was preparering to answer :)

Comment: @Dilek - I can :) However, if your answer is more specific, for example with reference to the framework in use, it could still be better than this. More answers never hurt in my opinion.

Comment: Wont be more than yours I need to spend a few years here for beter knowledge and english lang. lol